# How does method overriding work?

Tags: java, overriding

Look at the following code snippet:

```
class A
{
  void fun1()
   {

    System.out.println("fun1 of A");
    fun2();
   }

  void fun2()
  {
     System.out.println("fun2 of A");
  }
}
class B extends A
{
  void fun2()
  {
    System.out.println("fun2 of B");
   }
}
```

in main method:

```
A a=new B();
a.fun1()
```

The output is:

```
fun1 of A
fun2 of B
```

Can you please explain this output.

According to me `a.fun1` is calling `fun1` of `A` since `fun1` is not overriden by `B`(otherwise it would have called `fun1` of `B`). And, `fun2()` in `fun1` of `A` is calling `fun2` of `B` since `fun2` is overriden and object of B is created at runtime. Am I thinking in correct direction ?

Comment: Yes. SO thinks this is too short for even a comment, let alone answer.

Comment: You've just asked an answer.

Comment: @MarounMaroun That's funny. And you answered the question.

Comment: On a side note, you can't override static methods. So if you made all the methods static, it would print out `fun1 of A fun2 of A`

Comment: Why it is not calling the inherited method 'fun1()' in B ?

Answer (score 2):

It has been answered but I'm putting this as an answer anyway because I object to the simplification of the example code and I can't properly express that in a comment. Using names such as A and B and fun() really does not help anyone understand anything, including yourself. Try this:

```
class Animal {

  public void  makeSound(){
    System.out.println("<silence>");
  }
} 

class Cow extends Animal {
  public void  makeSound(){
    System.out.println("Moooooooo");
  } 
}


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

       Animal animal = new Cow();
       animal.makeSound(); // what sound is the animal going to make?
    }

}
```

If you use something "realistic" that is easy to envision, it all of a sudden becomes almost self-explanatory.

Note: I purposely left out any reference to the abstract keyword because that is not within the context of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is mostly correct. Just remember that all functions in Java are virtual and methods will be called depending on run-time type of the object you're working with. The trick is that when you do `fun2();` there is an implicit `this` so it becomes `this.fun2()`. Since this in your exapmle `this` points to an object of class `B`, the overriden method will be called.

Comment: According to you, a.fun1() is calling the inherited method fun1 in B, since the object is of B ?

Comment: @VikasMangal yes, but the B.fun1() is inherited from A.fun1() and not overriden in any way so it's identical to A.fun1()

Comment: I think you are wrong here. When I make the method fun2 of A private. The output is: fun1 of A, fun2 of A. Therefore it is not calling the inherited method, it is calling the  method which is in class A.

Comment: @VikasMangal yes, private methods are special, they are not inherited and hence are not virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Not much more to say than that your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
A a=new B();
```

That line says that get the implementations in the type `B` when they called. Keep it simple. You are right.