# How does a call to overridden method is resolved in method overriding?

Tags: java, overriding

According to my understanding, if call to a method is made which is overridden then the method is decided on the basis of the object at the runtime.

for eg.

```
class A
{
  void fun1()
    {
      System.out.println("fun1 of clss A");
    }
}
class B extends A
{
  void fun1()
  {
     System.out.println("fun1 of class B");
   }
}
```

Now,

```
A a=new B();
a.fun1();
```

The output is:

```
fun1 of class B
```

**But**,

I am not able to understand the output of following program

```
class A
{
  void fun1()
    {
      System.out.println("fun1 of clss A");
    }
}
class B extends A
{
  void fun1()
  {
     System.out.println("fun1 of class B");
     fun2();
   }
  private void fun2()
 {
    System.out.println("fun2 of class B");
 }
}
class C extends B
{
    private void fun2()
 {
    System.out.println("fun2 of class C");
 }
}
```

Now,

```
A a =new C();
a.fun1();
```

It is giving output:

```
fun1 of class B
fun2 of class B
```

(It means not the inherited fun1 but the fun1 is class B is getting executed)

Why ? fun1 is overriden but it is not in class C and object of C is created at runtime? Why fun1 of B is getting executed?

Comment: Short answer: inheritance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does method overriding work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556202/how-does-method-overriding-work)

Comment: @HarryBlargle This guy asked both the questions. I think he likes to ask same questions again and again.

Comment: @HarryBlargle Please look at the edited question. and sorry but I am new to this and finding difficulty in understanding the concepts.

Comment: @Vikas Mangal: You should search for a beginners book or a tutorial, the internet has plenty of them instead of flooding this site with questions.

Answer (score 2):

`C` doesn't override the method. It therefore inherits its super type's implementation. That's the one being invoked.

Comment: please look at the edited question.

Comment: @VikasMangal Well now you're just changing a bunch of things. `private` methods are not inherited.